# Not able to create a SignUp page using Django

Tags: python, django

I am not able to create a User Registration page using Django where I have used a Profile model with the OnetoOne field with the default User model.
**views.py**

```
def SignUpView(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = SignUpForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            new_profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            new_profile.user = new_user
            userName = new_user.username
            password = new_profile.password1
            new_user.save(commit=True)
            new_profile.save(commit=True)
            user = authenticate(username = userName, password = password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('blog-home')
    else:
        user_form = SignUpForm()
        profile_form = ProfileForm()

    context = {
        'user_form': user_form, 
        'profile_form': profile_form,
    }

    return render(request, 'user/signup.html', context=context)
```

**forms.py**:

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2']

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['user', 'email']
```

**models.py**:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # img = 
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=500)
    location = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Profile for {self.user.username}'
```

It is displaying an error message on the signup page as : 
**ValueError at /signup/
ModelForm has no model class specified**.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because there's a typo in your meta class declaration. 
Change it to - `class Meta`. Note the case.

Comment: Thanks now the page is being displayed but actually it's not working. Nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this to get the `User` model?

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to - class Meta

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2']

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['user', 'email']
```

Comment: I have already changed that and the page is opening properly but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If this isn't a form based on a model, don't inherit from **forms.ModelForm**, just use an ordinary **forms.Form**.